# Optimum Radius and Height of Frustum of a Right Circular Cone with Set Volume

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

I have worked out how to find the optimum surface area dimensions for a full cone with a set volume, but am unsure how to go about this when the cone is truncated (bottom pointed end cut off)

How do I find the optimum dimensions (radius and height) of a frustum cone with a set volume? I've derived the below volume and surface area formulas for a frustum cone.

$$V = \frac{1}{3}\pi h(R^2 + Rr + r^2)$$

$$SA = \pi(R + r)[(R-r)^2 + h^2]^{1/2} $$

I then found what h was using the first volume formula:

$$h = \frac{3V}{\pi(R^2 + Rr + r^2)}$$

Then I subbed h into the SA formula such that:

$$SA = \pi(R + r)\left[(R-r)^2 +  \frac{9V^2}{\pi^2(R^2 + Rr + r^2)^2}\right]^{1/2} $$

I think that I am supposed to use differential calculus now to find the critical values/local minimum but am not sure how to do this because there are two different radii values?

Comment: I edited your comment. Please familiarize yourself with typesetting on this site. It will make your question more readable, and more likely to be answered. Also, I fixed your third formula. You forgot to square the $h$

Answer (score 1):

For $R=r$ you have $SA=2V/R$, which has no minimum as it tends to $0$ for $R\to\infty$.

Notice however that your formula does NOT include the area of the bases.